# How do I architect a program involving mutation and objects referencing each other?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to mutate data in Rust when there are immutable references, but I cannot manage to get a successful build even when using `RefCell`

Here's the original code which doesn't build because `env` is borrowed twice:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Environment {
    machines: HashMap<String, Box<Machine>>,
}

struct Machine {}

impl Environment {
    fn get_machine(&self, key: String) -> &Box<Machine> {
        return match self.machines.get(&key) {
            Some(value) => value,
            _ => panic!("Unknown machine {}", key),
        };
    }
}

impl Machine {
    fn start(&self, env: &mut Environment) {
        env.machines
            .insert(String::from("m1"), Box::new(Machine {}));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut env = Environment {
        machines: HashMap::new(),
    };
    env.machines
        .insert(String::from("m1"), Box::new(Machine {}));

    let machine = env.get_machine(String::from("m1"));
    machine.start(&mut env);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `env` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:33:19
   |
32 |     let machine = env.get_machine(String::from("m1"));
   |                   --- immutable borrow occurs here
33 |     machine.start(&mut env);
   |             ----- ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |             |
   |             immutable borrow later used by call
```

I tried to refactor using `RefCell`:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Environment {
    machines: RefCell<HashMap<String, Box<Machine>>>,
}

struct Machine {}

impl Environment {}

impl Machine {
    fn start(&self, machines: &mut HashMap<String, Box<Machine>>) {
        // Operations which modifies the environment
        machines.insert(String::from("m2"), Box::new(Machine {}));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let env = &mut Environment {
        machines: RefCell::new(HashMap::new()),
    };
    env.machines
        .borrow_mut()
        .insert(String::from("m1"), Box::new(Machine {}));

    match env.machines.borrow().get(&String::from("m1")) {
        Some(machine) => machine.start(&mut env.machines.borrow_mut()),
        _ => panic!("Unknown machine"),
    };
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Now I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:28:58
```

I am not sure how to architect a program involving mutation and objects referencing each other in Rust.

Comment: As I said on your [previous, deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578576/how-to-have-two-objects-that-need-each-other-in-rust?noredirect=1#comment119448612_67578576): Your code allows for memory unsafety because `machine.start` could go through `env` to get to the machine itself and invalidate it because of the mutable reference. Break your `env` into smaller pieces (that don't contain `machine`!) and pass only the smaller pieces you need to start.

Comment: You haven't done that, and now instead of getting a compile time error, you've moved it to a runtime error, because you are still *trying to borrow `env` multiple times concurrently*.

Comment: I did think about breaking `env` in multiple parts, but I still need to pass the list of machines (although it can be immutable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `Box<Machine>` with `Rc<Machine>`, then you'll be able to create another reference to the machine outside of the borrow.  This will use reference counting, so you need to be a bit careful not to create a cycle, but this will allow you to clone the reference to the `Rc<Machine>` to create a new independent reference:

```
let env = &mut Environment { machines: RefCell::new(HashMap::new()) };
env.machines.borrow_mut().insert(String::from("m1"), Rc::new(Machine {}));

let machine = match env.machines.borrow().get(&String::from("m1")) {
    Some(machine) => machine.clone(),  // New reference created here
    _ => panic!("Unknown machine")
};
println!("Hello, world!");
// The previous .borrow() is now out of scope, so the following .borrow_mut() is allowed
machine.start(&mut env.machines.borrow_mut())
```

Comment: I tried this, replacing `Box` with `Rc` but the code then complains that the Environment instantiation "creates a temporary which is freed while still in use"

Comment: Can you show the code where the error occurs?  Are you sure you cloned the machine value when `.get()`ing it?

Comment: It says:
   |
21 |     let env = &mut Environment { machines: RefCell::new(HashMap::new()) };
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
29 |     machine.start(&mut env.machines.borrow_mut())    
   |                        ------------------------- a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
30 | }

Comment: I've modified my answer to include the full contents of `fn main()`.  The only other changes I've made to your example above is to change `Box` to `Rc` in `struct Environment` and `fn start()`.  This compiles and runs for me without the error you're receiving.  Can you determine if your version deviates from this?  The compiler error you're getting implies that `env` is going out of scope before the call to `machine.start()`, but that doesn't happen in my code snippet

Comment: I'm using https://play.rust-lang.org/, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Between Shepmaster's advice and your advice to use `Rc` I was able to get it working. Thank you both for your help.